# Angular directives get different parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page that calls a directive two times

```
<div>
  <my-directive attr="attr1" attrSib="attr2"></my-directive>
  <my-directive attr="attr2" attrSib="attr1"></my-directive>
</div>
```

I want both to communicate with each other so I tried to use parent scope to set a function, as example of my directive

```
.directive('myDirective', function(_) {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  templateUrl: 'template.html',
  controller: 'directiveController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl',
  scope: {
    attr: '=',
    attrSib: '='
  },
  
};
```

directiveController is like

```
var siblingName = vm.selfName + attrSib;
$scope.parent[selfName + attr] = function(){...};
....
/*on event*/$scope.parent[sibling]();
```

But I noticed that the first directive has a parent scope with id x, while second has a scope parent with id x+1 which is the child of x...

How can I make both have same parent? I'd like to not use rootScope broadcast.

Comment: add new attribute as `parent` for each of them, so you have `$scope[parent][sibling]();`

Answer (score 0):

If you add new attribute as i said in comment, you will separate all of you directives from each other, here i add `parent`, so you could call parent with `attr` or `sibling` easily, from one parent.

```
<div>
  <my-directive parent="iParent" attr="attr1" sibling="attr2"></my-directive>
  <my-directive parent="iParent" attr="attr2" sibling="attr1"></my-directive>
</div>

$scope[parent][sibling]();
```

**for example**

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  $scope.parent = [
      {name: "A"},
      {name: "B"}
  ]
  
    $scope.parent2 = [
      {name: "C"},
      {name: "D"}
  ]
})

app.directive("myDirective", function(){
  return {
    template: "<p>you call {{node.name}}</p>",
    scope: {
      index: "=",
      parent: "="
    },
    link: function(scope){
       scope.node = scope.parent[scope.index];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <h3>parent 1 </h3>

    <div my-directive parent="parent" index="0"></div>
    <div my-directive parent="parent" index="1"></div>
    
    <h3>parent 2 </h3>
    <div my-directive parent="parent2" index="0"></div>
    <div my-directive parent="parent2" index="1"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Edited the post for better explain